# Bulk read in pymongo loop

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

currently, using pymongo, I'm iterating through a very large mongodb collection like this:

```
client = MongoClient(config.get('db','url'))
db=client.mydatabase
incomings = db.incoming.find()

for incoming in incomings:
    do something with incoming
```

Instead, with each loop iteration, I would like to read a certain amount of dicts/documents at once, so I won't get dict after dict from the database, but rather a set of dicts like this: `[{...},{...},{...},...]`

I'm aiming to reduce the load on the database. If with the use of the cursor it's already ideal, then I'm fine with my current solution.

BTW, the incoming collection is being pounded with hundreds of documents per second, it serves as a permanent buffer for incoming zmq messages.

Can you provide me with any performance improvement considerations, especially for my case with many data coming in and out?

With storing data, I'm already buffering using `insert_many` instead of single inserts, and of course data is leaving the collection by using `delete_many`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing a performance bottleneck, [consider using a replicaset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/); once set up, do your reads from a secondary database (set your [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) to [secondaryPreferred](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondaryPreferred)).

Comment: Thank you very much, it absolutely makes sense to scale, the load on each server will say thank you to such a decision. And I say thank you to you!

Comment: this does  not answer the question asked